# In unity game appears dark exporting to ios what happened?

Tags: unity, ios

Everything appeared darker when I exported my game to iOS.  I only updated my Unity to 4.6.3 .
Any idea why?

Comment: What kind of lights are you using? Keep in mind that Unity is free to ignore any point-lights not marked as "important" when framerate becomes low.

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I got it: Using "vertex lit" instead of "forward".

Comment: hm perhaps this means that the forward renderer isn't supported on iOS? That would be unfortunate.